# How to preg_replace same items in one subject php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, matching

I have a question regarding one case.

I'm using php preg_replace() function to format data from this string:

```
12:05 Place1 12:40 14:00 16:30 Place2 "Test" 29 Janury
```

I need it to be outputed like this:

```
<li>29 January - Place1 - 12:05</li>
<li>29 January - Place2 "Test" - 12:40 14:00 16:30</li>
```

My regular expression:

```
/(\d[0-9]:\d[0-9]).+?(\D+).+?(\d[0-9]\s(January|February|March))/
```

I'm currently using something like this:

```
$text = "12:05 Place1 12:40 14:00 16:30 Place2 "Test" 29 Janury";
$data = preg_replace("/(\d[0-9]:\d[0-9]).+?(\D+).+?(\d[0-9]\s(January|February|March))/", "<li>$3 - $2 - $1</li>", $text);
echo $data;
```

The problem it shows only first matches,

29 January - Place1 - 12:05

Maybe someone know how to solve this case?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, you need to escape the `"` inside `$text`. You also misspelled `January` as `Janury`. I don't see how you got any result from that code.

Comment: After I fix those problems, there's still only one match for it in the string. Why do you expect it to find more than the first match?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't pay enough attantion for payload text, my mistake :(
Though even after this fixes it still can return only one line of data.
I was just interested if it is possible to get all the data :)
Thanks for response!

Comment: What do you mean by "all the data"? Your example only has one month, what more do you expect it to match?

Comment: Why do you write `\d[0-9]` instead of `\d\d`? And what about days with only 1 digit, like `5 January`?

Comment: About days - that's not main case, but can be easily changed for '\d\d' or '\d{1,2}' or some other :)

Comment: Right. That still doesn't answer my question about what you're really trying to do. You keep saying it only finds the first match, but there's only one match in `$text`. What is the second match you expect it to replace?

Comment: I showed in the example what I expect to see from this replace, this expression works, but it matches only once and I thought that it will match everything :)
If try to match for example only place or time, that's not a proble, it maches every place & time and correctly outputing in list, but in current case it doesn't work

Comment: There's only one match in your `$text` string. If there are 2 matches, it matches both of them, see http://ideone.com/hWdl7O

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I understood you point :)
The problem was not in template, but with data and if add date - this template works fine. I just will remove expression for date because it may be or may not, and places with time - are always appears.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do in one regex because you want to use a match from the end of the string before the PCRE engine has reached it. You need to do this in two steps:

1. `preg_match()` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to capture the date from the end of the string into another variable. Use the offset it provides to truncate the original string.
2. `preg_match_all()` the truncated string to get the times & places as an array, then iterate the array to use each match & the date variable to create the list. `'/((?:\s*+\d\d:\d\d)++)\s++((?:.(?!\d\d:\d\d\s))++)\s*+/'` is a suitable pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it also works :)
I think that my question is resolved)